# Waiting for http results before showing correct html block

Tags: angularjs

In an Angularjs view I have two `div` blocks:

```
<div ng-if="countApps() == 0">

</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-if="countApps() > 0">

<div>
```

My controller provides a function to return the number of applications:

```
$scope.countApps = function(){
  return $scope.apps.length;
}
```

and to get the apps:

```
//controller
AppService.fetch().$promise.then(function(response){
  $scope.apps = response.apps;
})
```

The problem is that if the http request happens to be slow the `div` block for 0 apps gets shown for a second or two. Then it will change to the other block once the results load. I would like it to load the apps and then show the correct view.

Comment: If you use routes, then use resolve block. Otherwise it's trickier. Maybe just show loading or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

What if do not define $scope.apps before first AppService.fetch()?

Comment: You should give an answer not just you point of view __just saying__.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable as a flag and set it to true in the promise.
This way you only need to create on div and not use another div for zero case.

```
AppService.fetch().$promise.then(function(response){
   $scope.apps = response.apps;
   $scope.app_present = true;
})

<div ng-if="countApps() && app_present">
    This will only be shown when you get response. 
<div>
```

**EDIT:-**

In my opinion you should not have two div's rather based on the response you should add custom message in the promise part only, promise part should be used for assignment purposes.
Also if there are other divs for `countApp() === 0` case then logic for that should also in the promise part. Avoid creating div's for different values of response doesn't look good in the code.

Comment: In my case the `div`s have different information to show the user

Comment: yaa then you can use ` && app_present` in both the div's it should work, the basic idea is to show the div's only when you have got the response from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You may define your countApps() method in promise callback

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zy6Vs59UlTKQkzeVdupW?p=preview)

```
  //dummy example from plunker 
  AppService().then(function(result) {
    $scope.apps = result;

    $scope.countApps = function() {
      return $scope.apps;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it cause problem since before the response `countApps()` is not defined in the view and thus angular intrepolation will be confused , AFAIK this can cause problems in production. let me know if it works I am not sure here.

Comment: Angular expressions evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.

Comment: Another question that is better to use a variable instead method.

Comment: Okay thanks but I ran into a production error sometime back so was being cautious..:), this solution should also work.

Comment: Interest, I'll try to test it, but no problems before.

Comment: Yaa that is what I pointed out logic for such a thing should go into the promise part and just used in the view.